# Problema en consulta compleja Postgresql (Odoo)

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Tengo un problema con una consulta compleja. Se trata de ver todas las órdenes de ventas. La consulta es para un ERP llamado Odoo:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.ordenes_de_venta AS
    WITH tabla as (
    SELECT
       po.id pos_id,
       sp_fecha(to_char(po.create_date, 'D')) AS "día de la semana",
       to_char(po.create_date, 'FMDD')::integer AS día,
       to_char(po.create_date, 'FMMM')::integer AS mes,
       to_char(po.create_date, 'YYYY')::integer AS año,
       to_char(po.create_date, 'HH24:MI:SS')::time AS hora,
       po.create_date fechor,
       po.pos_reference pedido,
       pol.product_id AS "id producto",
       pt.name AS "nombre producto",
       pol.price_unit::numeric(10,2) AS "precio unidad",
       pol.qty AS cantidad,
       pol.discount AS descuento,
       (pol.qty::NUMERIC(10,2) * (pol.price_unit::NUMERIC(10,2) -(pol.discount::NUMERIC(10,2)*
       pol.price_unit::NUMERIC(10,2)/100::NUMERIC(10,2))))::NUMERIC(10,2) AS subtotal,
       pol.purchase_price::numeric(10,2) AS coste,
       pol.margin::numeric(10,2) AS margen,
       substring(pol.name, 1, strpos((pol.name)::text, '/')-1) AS "localización",
       bn.name AS marca,
       sbn.name AS submarca,
       pol.product_description AS "descripción producto",
       pc.name AS "categoría",
       pse.name temporada,
       pa.name ||': '|| pav.name atributo,
       pp.default_code AS "referencia interna",
       rp.name AS proveedor,
       round((pol.margin/NULLIF((pol.qty * pol.price_unit * (100::numeric(10,4) - pol.discount) / 100::numeric(10,4))::numeric(10,2),0))::numeric,2) "margen%"
   FROM pos_order po
       LEFT JOIN pos_order_line pol ON pol.order_id = po.id
       LEFT JOIN product_product pp ON pp.id = pol.product_id
       LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id
       LEFT JOIN brand_name bn ON bn.id = pol.brand_id
       LEFT JOIN subbrand_name sbn ON sbn.id = pol.subbrand_id
       LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON pc.id = pt.categ_id
       LEFT JOIN product_supplierinfo ps ON ps.product_tmpl_id = pp.product_tmpl_id
       LEFT JOIN res_partner rp ON rp.id = ps.name
       LEFT JOIN product_season pse ON pse.id = pt.season
       LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value_product_product_rel pavppr ON pavppr.product_product_id = pol.product_id
       LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value pav ON pav.id = pavppr.product_attribute_value_id
       LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.id = pav.attribute_id
   ORDER BY atributo)

   SELECT  "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido, "id producto", "nombre producto", "precio unidad", pos_id
cantidad, descuento, subtotal, margen, coste, localización, marca, submarca, "descripción producto", categoría, temporada, string_agg(atributo,',') atributos, 
"referencia interna", string_agg(proveedor,','), "margen%"

   FROM tabla
   GROUP BY "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, "id producto", "nombre producto", "precio unidad", pos_id,
cantidad, descuento, subtotal, coste, localización, marca, submarca, "descripción producto", categoría, temporada,
"referencia interna", margen, "margen%", pedido
   ORDER BY fechor DESC;
```

La tabla po (pos_order) guarda las órdenes de compra, pero no muestra todos los datos que son necesarios, por eso he creado esta vista. No puedo poner los datos que estoy analizando porque son de una empresa.

El problema de esta consulta es que cuando un cajero coge un producto y lo pasa por el lector de códigos de barras, luego pasa otro y vuelve a pasar el primero si yo hago `select * from ordenes_de_venta where pedido = 'Pedido 12323'` no me dirá (entre otros muchos campos):

```
    pos_id    pedido producto cantidad precio descuento subtotal
    1         12323  Gafas    1        15,90  0         15,90
    1         12323  Collar   2        4,95   0         9,90
    1         12323  Gafas    1        15.90  0         15.90
```

Sino:

```
    pos_id pedido producto cantidad precio descuento subtotal
    1      12323  Gafas    1        15,90  0         15,90
    1      12323  Collar   2        4,95   0         9,90
```

Si busco en la tabla po (pos_order) encontraré que sí están las 3 líneas, pero al hacer los joins se borra una de ellas, como si hiciera un `distinct`.

Con la consulta `select * from pos_order_line pol join pos_order po on po.id = pol.order_id where  po.pos_reference= 'Pedido 12323';`sí muestra todo lo que busco.

Gracias.

Comment: Con tu última edición, te diré que lo que expones no es posible. Si puedes incluir algo que podamos reproducir, eso sería útil. De cualquier forma, te sugiero de depurar la consulta por medio de ir simplificándola hasta encontrar cual porción causa que algunos registros desaparezcan.

Comment: @sstan actualicé las tablas para que se vea un poco más claro a lo que me refiero. Se repiten todos los campos. Iré haciendo lo que me dices de simplificar.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, he conseguido hacer que funcione. Descuadran un par de céntimos, pero nada de importancia. Veré pronto en qué pedidos ocurre.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_fecha(n_dia char)
RETURNS varchar
AS $$
DECLARE
    dia_semana varchar;   
BEGIN
    dia_semana = 
        (SELECT
            CASE n_dia
                WHEN '2' THEN 'Lunes'
                WHEN '3' THEN 'Martes'
                WHEN '4' THEN 'Miércoles'
                WHEN '5' THEN 'Jueves'
                WHEN '6' THEN 'Viernes'
                WHEN '7' THEN 'Sábado'
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Domingo'
            END);

    RETURN dia_semana;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP VIEW public.ordenes_de_venta;
DROP SEQUENCE proxima_fila_id;
CREATE SEQUENCE proxima_fila_id;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.ordenes_de_venta AS
WITH lineas_de_ventas as (
SELECT
    sp_fecha(to_char(po.create_date, 'D')) AS "día de la semana",
    to_char(po.create_date, 'FMDD')::integer AS día,
    to_char(po.create_date, 'FMMM')::integer AS mes,
    to_char(po.create_date, 'YYYY')::integer AS año,
    to_char(po.create_date, 'HH24:MI:SS')::time AS hora,
    po.create_date fechor,
    po.pos_reference pedido,
    pol.product_id AS "id producto",
    pol.price_unit::numeric(10,2) AS "precio unidad",
    pol.qty AS cantidad,
    pol.discount AS descuento,
    pol.brand_id,
    pol.subbrand_id,
    (pol.qty::NUMERIC(10,2) * (pol.price_unit::NUMERIC(10,2) - (pol.discount::NUMERIC(10,2)*pol.price_unit::NUMERIC(10,2)/100::NUMERIC(10,2))))::NUMERIC(10,2) AS subtotal,
    pol.purchase_price::numeric(10,2) AS coste,
    pol.margin::numeric(10,2) AS margen,
    substring(pol.name, 1, strpos((pol.name)::text, '/')-1) AS "localización",
    pol.product_description AS "descripción producto",
    round((pol.margin/NULLIF((pol.qty * pol.price_unit * (100::numeric(10,4) - pol.discount) / 100::numeric(10,4))::numeric(10,2),0))::numeric,2) "margen%"
FROM pos_order po
     LEFT JOIN pos_order_line pol ON pol.order_id = po.id

ORDER BY po.id),

nombres as (
SELECT "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido, "precio unidad", descuento, subtotal, coste, margen, localización, "descripción producto", "margen%", "id producto", brand_id, subbrand_id,
    pp.product_tmpl_id ptemplate, cantidad,
    pt.name AS "nombre producto",
    pt.season,
    pt.default_code as "referencia interna",
    nextval('proxima_fila_id') as fila,
    pc.name AS "categoría"

FROM lineas_de_ventas
    LEFT JOIN product_product pp ON pp.id = "id producto"
    LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id
    LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON pc.id = pt.categ_id
    ),

marcas as(
SELECT distinct "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido, "precio unidad", descuento, subtotal, coste, margen, localización, "descripción producto", "margen%", "id producto",
    "nombre producto", categoría, fila, ptemplate, season, cantidad, "referencia interna",
    bn.name AS marca,
    sbn.name AS submarca
FROM nombres
    LEFT JOIN brand_name bn ON bn.id = brand_id
    LEFT JOIN subbrand_name sbn ON sbn.id = subbrand_id
    LEFT JOIN product_supplierinfo ps ON ps.product_tmpl_id = ptemplate),

proveedores as(
SELECT distinct pp.id,
    pp.product_tmpl_id,
    rp.name prv
FROM product_product AS pp
    LEFT JOIN product_supplierinfo ps ON ps.product_tmpl_id = pp.product_tmpl_id
    LEFT JOIN res_partner rp ON rp.id = ps.name
),

proveedor_linea_de_ventas as(
    SELECT "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido, "precio unidad", descuento, subtotal, coste, margen, localización, "descripción producto", "margen%", "id producto", 
    "nombre producto", categoría, fila, marca, submarca, product_tmpl_id, season, cantidad, "referencia interna",
    string_agg(prv,',') AS "proveedor/es"
    FROM marcas
    LEFT JOIN proveedores p ON p.id = "id producto"

    GROUP BY "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido,"precio unidad", descuento, subtotal, coste, margen, localización, "descripción producto", "margen%", "id producto", 
    "nombre producto", categoría, fila, marca, submarca, product_tmpl_id,season, cantidad, "referencia interna"
),

atributos_y_temporada as (
SELECT "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido, "precio unidad", descuento, subtotal, coste, margen, localización, "descripción producto", "margen%", "id producto", 
    "nombre producto", categoría, fila, marca, submarca, product_tmpl_id, "proveedor/es",cantidad, "referencia interna",
    pse.name temporada,
    pa.name ||': '|| pav.name atributo
    FROM proveedor_linea_de_ventas
    LEFT JOIN product_season pse ON pse.id = season
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value_product_product_rel pavppr ON pavppr.product_product_id = "id producto"
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value pav ON pav.id = pavppr.product_attribute_value_id
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.id = pav.attribute_id
    order by pa.name, pav.name
)

SELECT 
    "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, pedido, "id producto", "nombre producto", "referencia interna", "precio unidad", 
    cantidad, descuento, subtotal, margen, coste, localización, marca, submarca, "descripción producto", categoría, temporada, string_agg(atributo,',') atributos, 
    "proveedor/es", "margen%"
    FROM atributos_y_temporada

    GROUP BY 
    "día de la semana", "día", mes, año, hora, fechor, "id producto", pedido, "id producto", "nombre producto", "precio unidad", 
    cantidad, descuento, subtotal, margen, coste, localización, marca, submarca, "descripción producto", categoría, temporada,
    "margen%", fila, "proveedor/es", cantidad, "referencia interna"
    ORDER BY fechor DESC;
```